# In first box there are $2$ white and $2$ black balls, in second $5$ white and $7$ black balls.

Tags: probability

In first box there are $2$ white and $2$ black balls, in second $5$ white and $7$ black balls. We transfer $2$ balls from first box to second box. Next, we transfer $2$ balls from second box to first box. If we know that after doing all of that in first box we have all balls same colour, what is the probability that they are all black?

This is typical task with conditional probability. At the end I got result $\frac{21}{31}$ , which is, according to solutions of the book from which is this task, complement of result I should get ( $\frac{10}{31}$ )

Comment: I got same result as you did.

Comment: Put shortly, you are right and the author is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, it ought to be more likely that they are all black, as transferring two white to box 2, then two black back to box 1 is more probable than transferring two black to box 2, then two white to box 1 (the two first-transfers are equally probable, but there is a big difference between the two second-transfers).

And actually doing the calculations, I also get $\frac{21}{31}$ versus $\frac{10}{21}$, with the all-black outcome being the more likely one.